# Eliminating empty rows from PowerShell Object Output

Tags: powershell, object

Is it a way to remove the rows which doesn't contain any value-data?
For this script, for example, the 'Department' value field is empty, I would like to trim it out.

```
    [System.Object]$ADOutputSelectedValues = [ordered] @{

    'FirstName'  = $ADReturnObject.FirstName
    'LastName'   = $ADReturnObject.LastName
    'Location'   = $ADReturnObject.Location
    'Department' = $ADReturnObject.Department
    'Epost'      = $ADReturnObject.Epost
    'Id'         = $ADReturnObject.Id

}

$Output = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $ADOutputSelectedValues

$Output
```

**Edit:**
The current output is:

```
FirstName  : Donald
LastName   : Duck
Location   : Dugburg
Department : 
Epost      : Donald@Duck.com
Id         : 313
```

Would like it to look like this:

```
FirstName  : Donald
LastName   : Duck
Location   : Dugburg
Epost      : Donald@Duck.com
Id         : 313
```

In advance, thanks.

Comment: you can't remove a property. [*grin*] instead, you need to build a new object that leaves the property out by using something like `Select-Object`. ///// **_however_**, that will remove the item from ALL objects, not just the one. if you add code to  remove the prop from only the one ... you will have a collection that cannot be exported to a CSV since that requires that the 1st object decide what all other objects props will be.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It's not possible to to filter it out by select | where {$_.Value -notlike ' '} or something like that?

Comment: i presumed you wanted to modify an existing custom object - apparently you want to modify a hashtable. oops! [*blush*] you cannot REMOVE a  property, but you can remove a key-value pair from a hashtable by using the `.Remove()` method. /////  still, if you make a custom object of that item, you will need to be careful to make the same change to all the objects IF you intend to export them to a CSV file, since the 1st object will determine the columns for all the remaining objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own coding, I've made a function to help with cases like this.

```
Function Remove-EmptyValuesFromHashtable
{
    Param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [Hashtable] $Hashtable )

    $NewHashtable = @{}

    foreach ($Key in $Hashtable.Keys)
    {
        if ($Hashtable.$Key -as [Bool])
        {
            $NewHashtable += @{ $Key=$Hashtable.$Key }
        }
    }

    return $NewHashtable
}
```

Note that "empty values" includes $Null, empty string, $False. If you don't want it to remove $False values, you'll have to modify it.